# How can I create a Wi-Fi hosted network at 5GHz?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, network-adapter

Is it possible to create a hosted Wi-Fi network at 5GHz, that is not connected to the Internet?

I read [on this site](https://forums.intel.com/s/question/0D50P0000490BJvSAM/wlanhostednetworkquerystatus-function-does-not-work-in-11a-mode?language=en_US) that:

> "If the WLAN card is NOT connected to a Wi-Fi network , then the soft-AP it generates is on 2.4 GHz".

But I am not sure if someone have achieve this already. Also, if it is possible to use a portable device (a USB Wi-Fi adapter with SoftAP mode) to generate a the 5GHz hosted network.

I already have `softap` and `hostednetwork` mode on, and a `hostednetwork` working at 2.7GHz. The PC has a dual Wi-Fi adapter allowing AC mode and I am running Windows 8 (and also working at 2.7GHz in Windows 10).

Comment: It's certainly possible, and e.g. very easy under Linux. If it's possible with whatever Windows version you are using, whichever Wi-Fi adapter with whatever driver version you are using, or if a bug or API oversight is preventing it from doing so, is a different question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have done it in Linux, where the interface allows you directly choose 5GHz or 2.4GHz. The problem is that I am not sure how to do it on Windows. I have change the Wifi adapter properties to: 1)Wireless mode 802.11a/b/g; 2)HT Mode: VHT mode; 3)Prefered band 5.2Ghz

Comment: Actually, I realized I created a hotspot in Linux, but still not able to create a hosted network without internet connection. Could you please tell me how you did it? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure where you are stuck: With hostapd you get a network interface, and you can configure the rest in any way you want. Disable forwarding, and it won't connect to anything. Add specific routes and/or `iptables` rules, and you can filter out unwanted connections. It all depends on how the rest of your network is set up, and what exactly you want to achieve. Maybe make a new question with enough details for that?